# Yii2: Cannot perform RBAC migration (You should configure "authManager"...)

Tags: configuration, console, migration, yii2

As it is described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html) I'm trying to do the migration in order to let yii create the user authentication tables. However I get the error:

> Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'You should
>   configure "authManager" component to use database before executing
>   this migration.'

The authManager is present in the configuration but I still get that error. Configuration:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'db' => $db,
    'authManager'  => [
        'class'        => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        //            'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
    ],
    ...
],
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Problem was quite simple: The configuration was not used. `yii migrate` is a console command and usually the configuration for such commands is placed in a seperated file.

In case of **yii2-app-base** template, from which I have created my application, there is a `config/console.php` configuration file where the authManager needs to be declared. It is not sufficient to have it in the `config/web.php` declared only.

In case of **yii2-app-advanced** the authManager should be declared in `console/config/main.php` and not in the backend or frontend configuration files.

Comment: Then why [official doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) said this :  In case of yii2-advanced-app the authManager should be declared only once in common/config/main.php.